# React Native setting default value in setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

```
const getData = async (key) => {
        try {
        const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key)
        return jsonValue != null ? JSON.parse(jsonValue) : null;
        } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setYoutube(getData('youtube'));
    }, []);
```

Im getting the data for the storage, but when there is no data stored I want to have the value set to FALSE,

I want it like setYoutube(getData('youtube')) when getData('youtube') has no value, I want it to be false

Answer (score 0):

In your functional component :

```
[youtubedata,setYoutubedata] = useState(your_default_value_here)
```

[Check here the api reference for `useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)

ps: you better change the name of your variable from `setYoutube` to `setYoutubeData`

Otherwise your doing it right here:

```
 return jsonValue != null ? JSON.parse(jsonValue) : null;
```

so if there's no data the default value is null
but it's better to move your logic in the `useState` function

Comment: const [youtubeNoti, setYoutube] = useState(true); it is like this but when I first load the app is shows as negative

Comment: Try keeping the state variable and the setter equally named, so [youtubeData, setYoutubeData].. the last param of your useEffect is empty ,[]); so it will run once on init

Comment: @AlexHill as Rmaxx said the [] will render the function once if you remove it will render on every props change inside the component and this may guide you through an infinite loop rendering if your props/state keeps changing